# Python2.7 SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED with a valid .pem file

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, ssl-certificate

Curling

```
$ curl https://10.0.0.2
$ curl: (60) Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates
```

Tried curling with a certificate

```
$ curl -E /opt/software/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi-2017.11.5-py2.7.egg/certifi/cacert.pem https://10.0.0.2
```

And this works. so it looks to have a valid .pem file. Now trying in a python script with the same .pem file

test_bb.py

```
#!/opt/software/bin/python2.7
import ssl
import urllib2
import certifi

BB_URL = "https://10.0.0.2"
mycafile = certifi.where()
print "pem: %s" % mycafile
urllib2.urlopen(BB_URL, cafile=mycafile)
```

OUTPUT

```
$ ./test_bb.py 
pem: /opt/software/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi-2017.11.5-py2.7.egg/certifi/cacert.pem
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_bb.py", line 14, in <module>
    urllib2.urlopen(BB_URL, cafile=mycafile)
  File "/opt/software/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/opt/software/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/opt/software/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/opt/software/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/opt/software/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1241, in https_open
    context=self._context)
  File "/opt/software/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)>
```

Why is it throwing SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED for python when curl worked with the same .pem file?

How can I fix the python script so it doesnt throw the error?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy but im not specifying the .pem for both python script and curl, no? there shouldnt be a difference in certificate stores unless it means something other than .pem file?

Comment: Ahh -- right, I misread (thought you were specifying a client certificate, not a CA store).

Comment: This makes no sense: `curl -E` is used to specify a client certificate and cacert.pem should not contain such a certificate. And the python code that cares about CA certificate, not client certificate like curl anyway so you compare apples with oranges.

Comment: (Oh -- apparently I *didn't* misread so much).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I lack knowledge. whats the difference between a client certificate and cacert.pem? im just telling you that that worked though

Comment: @ealeon, a CA store is used to decide if the server's certificate is signed by a valid CA (used to prove who the server is *to the client*). A client certificate is used to prove who the client is *to the server*, in conjunction with a paired private key.

Comment: @ealeon: a client certificate is used by the client to authenticate itself against the server if the server requires so. You need to have certificate and private key to do this. A CA certificate or a trust store like cacert.pem is used by the client to verify the servers certificate. It should only contain CA certificates and no private keys. To use `curl` with trust store use the `--cacert` option not `-E`.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich so CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED is server rejecting the client's certificate or client not able to verify server's certificate?

Comment: @ealeon, ...that's the client failing to verify the server, typically because the server's certificate doesn't have a valid signature chain leading back to an entry in the client's CA store.

Comment: ah so i need to have a valid CA (this is not a .pem file? In the server that im trying to connect to, it has serverCA.pem and serverCA.cer). what is a valid CA (the .cer file?) and where do I put that information in python script?

Comment: @ealeon: the server certificate is not a CA certificate unless it is a self-signed certificate with basic constraints CA:true. A \*.pem format can contain CA certificates and non-CA certificates and private keys and more - it is just a format for many things. A \*.cer usually contains only a certificate. Once you have the proper CA file  the `cafile` argument is the correct way to use it in urllib2.

Comment: If you want to know what's in a .pem file, `openssl x509 -in yourfile.pem -noout -text` is your friend -- there's enough information there to figure out the pertinent basics.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich do you recommend any readings on this workflow? my understanding is that when a client is looking to connect to a server, it compares a certificate (?) server provides against a CA store the client has. If my understanding is correct then i need to update CA store with what's expected from the server. So then, i have two question: 1. where is client's CA store 2. how can i get the server certificate to put in to client's CA store?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy "...that's the client failing to verify the server, typically because the server's certificate doesn't have a valid signature chain leading back to an entry in the client's CA store. " you mean that there needs to be an entry in the client's CA store ie cacert.pem for server's certificate, correct? how do I get this server's certificate to put in to cacert.pem?

Comment: Not for the server's certificate itself, but for the certificate authority who signed that server's certificate. The server can also present its certificate along with a series of intermediate certificates, each with their own signature by their CA, so long as the chain leads back to a CA the client knows and trusts.

Comment: To find out where a Python install gets its CA store from, run `python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())"`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy DefaultVerifyPaths(cafile=None, capath='/opt/rh/jbcs-httpd24/root/etc/pki/tls/certs', openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE', openssl_cafile='/opt/rh/jbcs-httpd24/root/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem', openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR', openssl_capath='/opt/rh/jbcs-httpd24/root/etc/pki/tls/certs')

Comment: That said, you shouldn't be putting new CAs into your store unless you really, *really* trust them. Someone whose CA certificates you trust can, f/e, forge certificates that pretend to belong to other websites you use.

Comment: well, there are your answers (in terms of where the CA store in use by your Python code lives at). If that store is out-of-date (not covering changes in terms of old CAs going out of business / losing the community's trust and new ones coming in), there you are.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy right, now i need to know what to put in that cert.pem :)

Comment: I'd suggest finding a copy of `certs.pem` somewhere outside `/opt/rh`, ie. `/etc/pki/tls/certs.pem` on the root filesystem or such, that's actually getting updated when you install security updates &c.

Comment: (some installs will have a directory with one file per CA, and a symlink tree that points to each from its hash -- if certs.pem is empty, you may have the other style; same general rules apply, just use the certificate directory rather than the certificate file if that's the case for you).

Comment: ...if you find the working system install `curl` is using, you could also pass it as your `cafile` to urlopen.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you so much. things are much more clear now. im asking my friend for info on the certificate authority